# SAPUI5 bind only one entity to list

Tags: binding, odata, sapui5

I'm working on a SAPUI5 Project in SAP Web IDE. The idea is to consume data from a table in Backend System. The table is full of customers with different information to them. To achieve it I already created an oData service in the Backend System. The EntitySet provides all customers with all the concerning data. Calling just one Entity with the SAP Gateway client provides the same Information for just one customer. Now in the frontend, for the Fiori app, I already binded the oData Service to the project and achieved to set it as an template for an list and to display all customers in that list. 
But what I want is to have an toolbar with an search field, so the user can search for a customer ID and then display just that one searched customer concerning to the number in my list as a list item. So i don't want to have the whole entity set to bind that list, just the one the user searched for. 
So I think I have an function that is called when the user presses the search button and in that function I want to call the oData service Entity with the given ID in the search field. But I still don't get how to call the service and then bind it to the list item. 
I searched a lot in the internet and books but what I found is too old or not working or not exactly what I need.

Can anybody please help me with the call and the binding to the list item ?

Comment: Have you seen the following samples?

[Sample: List - Selection & Search](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListSelectionSearch/preview) and 
[Code: List - Selection & Search](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListSelectionSearch/code)

Comment: Thank you for those samples, but i think this is only half of what i need. In the example, the list works as a template, so that there are automatically list items created for every element in the EntitySet. But i cant do that because my EntitySet contains over 300 elements so i think it would be a little bit confusing to the users. So i can use the searchfield to select list items, but how to do it if i dont want to see these 300 customers until i searched ?
I think maybe i should use an filter of my OData Service or use the update method.

Comment: Is this [the floorplan](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/initial-page-floorplan/) you are looking for?

Comment: what you want to do is implement $filter, and have the EntitySet bring back only one result.

Comment: yes, that was what i was searching for, i implemented it with an filter and it works. 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to implement filters in SAPUI5.

Consider you have a List with a search field in your view as:

```html
<mvc:View
   controllerName="namespace.MainController"
   xmlns="sap.m"
   xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
   <List
      id="invoiceList"
      class="sapUiResponsiveMargin"
      width="auto"
      items="{/Invoices}" >
      <headerToolbar>
         <Toolbar>
            <SearchField width="50%" search="onFilterInvoices"/>
         </Toolbar>
      </headerToolbar>
      <items>
         <ObjectListItem>
           <!-- some items here            -->
         </ObjectListItem>
         
      </items>
   </List>
</mvc:View>
```

In the corresponding controller, you can do the following on Event triggered for the filter as:

```js
  onFilterInvoices : function (oEvent) {

   // build filter array
   var aFilter = [];
   var sQuery = oEvent.getParameter("query");
   if (sQuery) {
    aFilter.push(new Filter("ProductName", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery));
   }

   // filter binding
   var oList = this.byId("invoiceList");
   var oBinding = oList.getBinding("items");
   oBinding.filter(aFilter);
  }
```

More information of Filter:

- [sap.ui.model.Filter](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Filter)
- [Filter Operators](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.FilterOperator)
- [Filter working example](http://veui5infra.dhcp.wdf.sap.corp:8080/snippix/#38163)

Kindly let me know if this helps!